# How to unit test business logic and data access code

Tags: php, database, unit-testing

I'm working in a PHP project where testing software was neglected a long time.
The business logic is full of hard coded dependencies and immediate database access throught some hand-crafted (Oracle) SQL.

I've given up trying to build automated integration tests, because of complex database setup, tight compling to the (complex) database fixture and missing in-memory solutions.

For me it looks like the best place to start, is to test the business logic. Therefore I need to refactor the code to get the data access code seperated from the business logic, I guess. Still I'm struggeling with some basic design questions:

1. What is the preferred way to encapsulate/get rid of this complex SQL? **Is there any design pattern** which has some good hints on how to get data from the datasource in an configurable way? Injecting Propel Active Query objects seems the help in some cases, but in complex cases they will be very hard to mock I guess.
2. Is there a good **book** about Software Architecture + Unit Testing for Applications that need are heavily making use of their database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your 2nd question: [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052) is what you need: it explains several pattern to break dependencies to make a code testable.

Regarding your first question: it depends on your current case. Here are a few example described in depth in the book:

**Example 1 - Extract and override Call**

If you have a classe like (example isn't in php, but you'll get the idea)

```
class MyClass {
    int getNbEligibleItems(){
      List<Item> rawItems = readInDb();
      //Now count elegible ones
    }

    List<Item> readInDb(){
      //Directly call DB and return a raw list
    }
}
```

Then you could make `readInDb` virtual, and use a mock in tests:

```
class TestableMyClass : MyClass {
    override List<Item> readInDb(){
       //Return a list of hard code test items
    }
}
```

**Example 2 - Parametrized constructor**

If you have a class like this

```
class MyClass {
    private IDbReader _reader;

    MyClass(){
       _reader = new DbReader();
    }

    int work(){
       List<item> items = _reader.read();
       //Work with items
    }
}
```

Then it would be possible to changes constructors to

```
    MyClass() : this(new DbReader()){ }

    MyClass(IDbReader reader){
       _reader = reader;
    }
```

So it would be possible to mock db in tests

So, to put it in a nutshell: there are a lot of technique that could help in your case. We' need some code to be more specific. And I recommend reading this book as it provide lot of answers in those cases.

Comment: just for clarity, the code examples above are in Java, not PHP. It would work the same way in PHP with slightly different syntax.